# C++ Add node to beginning of linked list fails after 1 time. Trouble with other methods too

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list

So I have a linked list program semi working. I am just having some trouble with certain methods.... The ones I have documented bekiw are working except for delete from end which is acting weird.

I am using NetBeans on Mavericks with G++ as my compiler and C++11
[Here is a zip of all of the program files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u39gfqa1wtb6hhm/linker.zip)

Here is a list of the methods I am trying to make:

```
//working
int size() const;
/kind of 
void addToStart(Node *);
//working
void addToEnd(Node *);
//working
void printList();
//working
bool removeFromStart();
//kind of working
bool removeFromEnd();

//Still working on these
void removeNodeFromList(int);
void removeNodeFromList(string);
```

For now, I have to run removeFromEnd() twice in order for it to work. Meaning, I run it once at the beginning of the program and it does nothing, but every subsequent time, it actually does the deleting.

For addToStart() it works if I only run it once. I.E:

- I can run it once at the beginning of the program and print out the list
- I can run it once AFTER using addToEnd, but if I try it a second time, and I try to print out the list, it just keeps spitting out the value I tried to add.

addToEnd() works perfectly find if I just keep running that, but it fails if I:

Start out by using addToEnd() to add items, then use addToStart() ONCE and THEN try to use addToEnd() again. When I print out the list, it only prints out two objects and each of those is a copy of the last value I tried to insert.

```
void LinkedList::addToEnd(Node* ne) 
{
    Node** q = &myHead;
    while (*q) 
    {
        q = &(*q)->next;
    }

    *q = new Node(ne->itemName, ne->itemNo);
}

void LinkedList::printList() 
{
    Node* p = myHead;
    while (p != NULL) 
    {
        cout << p->itemNo << " " << p->itemName;
        cout << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
}

bool LinkedList::removeFromStart() 
{
    if (myHead == NULL) 
    {
        cout << "List is already empty";
    }
    else 
    {
        myHead = myHead->next;
    }
}

bool LinkedList::removeFromEnd() 
{
    if (myHead == NULL) 
        return false;

    //Empty the list if there's only one element
    if (myHead->next == NULL) 
    {
        delete myHead;
        myHead = NULL;
        myTail = NULL;
        return true;
    }

    // Find the last item in the list
    Node *temp = myHead;
    while (temp->next != myTail) 
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    delete myTail;
    temp->next = NULL;
    myTail = temp;
    return true;
}
```

Also, still trying to figure out the remove ones

```
void LinkedList::removeNodeFromList(int i) {


//Save the values
Node* p = myHead;
Node* temp = myHead->next;


    while (p) {

        if (p->itemNo == i) {

            p=temp;
        } else {
            p = p->next;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please correct your formatting and give an example program that shows erroneous behaviour

Comment: Fixed the formatting. To keep the question short without adding EVERYTHING, I linked to a zip containing all of my code.

Comment: Could you narrow this down to *one* problem you're having trouble with? I count five, and you haven't even bothered to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

You have a `tail` pointer, so why are you iterating through the list to find the end?  Additionally, why are you passing the node by pointer?

```
void LinkedList::addToEnd(Node ne) 
{
    if (myHead == nullptr) // empty list
    {
        myHead = myTail = new Node(ne);
        myTail->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        myTail->next = new Node(ne); // assuming Node has an accessible copy constructor
        myTail = myTail->next;
    }
}
```

The `removeFromStart` function has a memory leak:

```
bool LinkedList::removeFromStart() 
{
    if (myHead == nullptr) 
    {
        cout << "List is already empty";
        return false;
    }


    Node* temp = myHead;
    myHead = myHead->next;
    if (myTail == temp) // if there is only 1 element in the list, head == tail
    {
        myTail = myhead;
    }
    delete temp;
    return true;
}
```

Presumably, `removeFromEnd` should be removing the tail:

```
bool LinkedList::removeFromEnd() 
{
    if (myTail == nullptr) 
        return false;

    // unless you have a doubly-linked list, loop to find 1 before the tail
    Node* temp = nullptr;
    for (temp = myHead; temp && temp->next != myTail; temp = temp->next);


    if (myHead == temp) // when there is only 1 element in the list, head == tail
    {
        delete temp->next;
        myHead = nullptr;
        myTail = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        delete temp->next;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        myTail = temp;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And yes, you are using `new` (in your `addtoEnd` function), so you must use `delete` (**not** `free`!).

Side note:  You can write the remove code better by using `std::unique_ptr` (you can actually improve the code overall by using it everywhere) which will make your code for each about 4 lines long.  I'll leave that for you to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'm going to try them out now. And sorry,must have missed that new statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a member called `myTail` that you seem to be using 'sometimes'

In addFromEnd you do not update myTail.
In one of the remove functions you do not update myTail even though you might change it
But in RemoveFromTail you are trying to use it.

There is no reason that myTail will contain a valid value and when you try to use it you can get an error (cause the node may have been deleted) or an unexpected result because it just points somewhere in the list.

You should either lose it (since you can easily figure out the tail. it is the node where next==NULL) or take care to maintain it in every call that changes the List (only if the tail is affected obviously)

Since you are using c++11 a few suggestions:

use nullptr instead of NULL

use std::unique_ptr for Next. It will take care of 'deleting' nodes you are no longer using for you.

use a copy ctor for Node. If you ever make a change to Node you will not need to revisit this part of the code just the constructors.

If you are holding copies of objects in the list. Then it is much clearer if your interface will accept `const Node&` instead of `Node*`. To me Node* makes it seem like you are going to use the ptr the user supplied.

Comment: I just noticed that and put in what I am currently trying. I am not using new to allocate them.

Comment: He only needs to update `myTail` when he adds or removes items from the end of the list.

Comment: True but `removeNodeFromList` may end up removing from the end of the list which is why he needs to consider that myTail might be affected in methods that change the list

Comment: @odedsh Agreed, but only when the tail is affected.